# Best way to divide network?

Tags: networking, router, vlan, subnet

I own a small company that recently is outgrowing our current network.

Currently we have a 10.216.170.0/24 network and therefore only a limited number of available IP adresses.

Now, we have a single router (Cisco ASA 5510) with four ethernet ports:

eth0/0: Primary ISP
eth0/1: Backup ISP
eth0/2: Trunk port
eth0/3: currently not in use

There are 2 VLAN's configured to the trunk port, eth0/2.10 and eth0/2.20.

VLAN 10 is hosting our primary network (10.216.170.0/24) where everything is connected servers, workstations, printers, phones etc.

VLAN 20 is hosting a wireless guest network so that guests cannot access anything but the internet.

Now, i was thinking that we should divide our network so that our serves stayed on the old 10.216.170.0 network and create a new and preferably larger network for workstations, printers, phones etc.

But what is the best practice for this?. Should i just add another VLAN or add a subnet through the last available Ethernet port.

It is important that the new network still is able to communicate with the server network.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is a "best" way - there are simply ways that work better for your organization and ways that don't work for your organization. What matters is that the solution you choose is functional, reliable, and understandable to you, your bosses, and the people who will eventually be doing your job.

Comment: You've outgrown 254 ip addresses?

Comment: Why are you using a trunk port when you have a free Ethernet port? This is just a bottleneck, especially if they are Fast Ethernet ports instead of Gigabit Ethernet ones.